# /usr/local/bin/node: bad option: --expose-debug-as=v8debug

Tags: debugging, webstorm

In WebStorm, I have a `test01.js`:

```
function test() {
  console.log('test')
}

test()
```

When I run `test01.js`, I get bellow error in Console:

> /usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=56907 --expose-debug-as=v8debug /Users/Desktop/vue/vuejs-test01/src/test/test01.js
>   /usr/local/bin/node: bad option: --expose-debug-as=v8debug

Process finished with exit code 9

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to upgrade WebStorm to the most recent version - full support for Node.js 8+ debugging is only available since 2017.2.*.
If upgrading WebStorm is not an option, downgrade Node.js to v.6

Answer (score 0):

add `--inspect` value in node parameters.

In the `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Configuration -> Node Parameters`:

[image]

Then you apply it and re-run the `test01.js` file it will work.